# New to selenium. Please help. Unable to get focus on the current frame

Tags: selenium-ide

I am working on selenium from java code. In my current page there are two frames and i basically want to search for a text  in any of these two frames in the page.

Now, the problem is when i reach to this page, the focus doesn't seem to be coming on the newly opened page and therefore to the frames in it.

I tried following few options:
1. Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=top"), index=0/1, SelectFrame("//frame");
2. Tried selenium.getEval("document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0].contentWindow.document");
3. Also tried selenium.selectWindow() with name/title options.

I am still not able to get the focus on the current page and therefore not able to search for the intended text ( i am using selenium.isTextPresent("text") ) for this but it is not working because i guess focus it not shifting to the frame/page.

Could you please let me know what am i missing ?

Thanks,
Suman

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can't search across multiple frames.  If you want to look for the same string in either frame, you have to code two searches.  For example:

main.html:

```
<html>
    <frameset>
        <frame id="frame1" src="frame1.html">
        <frame id="frame2" src="frame2.jhtml">
    </frameset>
<html>
```

frame1.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello from frame 1!</p>
    </body>
<html>
```

frame2.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello from frame 2!</p>
    </body>
<html>
```

Then the following should find "Hello" in either frame:

```
foundHello = false;
selenium.selectFrame("relative=top");
selenium.selectFrame("id=frame1");
if selenium.isTextPresent("Hello") then foundHello = true;
selenium.selectFrame("relative=top");
selenium.selectFrame("id=frame2");
if selenium.isTextPresent("Hello") then foundHello = true;
if (foundHello) then ... blah blah blah ...
```